# Eclipse preference page with a CheckedTableviewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to create a preference page for my pluign as shown in the screeshot.

It looks like a CheckedTableViewer , I want to how I can easily implement this?

Is there something which I can reuse - I want the 'up' and 'down' buttons as well with the save in preference store.

I am using FieldLayoutPreferencePage.

[image]

Comment: I don't know of anything like this that can be reused. It is only a `CheckboxTableViewer` and two `Button` controls.

Comment: How to implement 'Up' and 'Down' button control ? Any example you can direct me into would be great.

Comment: Easy solution. Look at the source of the preference page in the screenshot. Press `Alt + Shift + F1` to see the preference page class name